How to get Next.js Action response in Server component?
This is my server actions:
import APIS from "@/src/constants/apis";
import { formDataToObject } from "@/src/lib/utils";
import { signupSchema } from "@/src/lib/validations";

import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { assert } from "superstruct";

export async function login(formData: FormData) {
  "use server";

  try {
    const res = await fetch(APIS.login, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      cookies().set("token", data.access_token, { maxAge: data.expires_in });
    } else {
      throw new Error(data.error);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      message: (err as { message: string }).message,
    };
  }

  redirect("/panel/dashboard/invoice");
}

export async function signup(formData: FormData) {
  "use server";

  try {
    // Validate form data first
    signupSchema.validate(formDataToObject(formData), {
      strict: true,
    });

    // If valid do a request
    const res = await fetch(APIS.register, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.ok) {
      cookies().set("token", data.access_token, { maxAge: data.expires_in });
    }

    if (!res.ok) throw new Error(data.error);
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      message: (err as { message: string }).message,
    };
  }

  redirect("/auth/login");
}

As you can see I return a message. but I want to show that message to user. is it possible to get the value of action (message here) in case of failure to show it to user? or I've to turn my actions and components to client side?

If you want the client to see the message, you could use a toast library. Here is the link to see the Documentation : https://vue-toastification.maronato.dev/. Anyhow, this library has an unresolved problem. When loading the page (onMounted), notifications are not displayed. For now we can get around the problem by adding a setTimeout of 0 milliseconds. Example :
onMounted(() => { 
  loadName() toast.info("Will not be displayed...") 
  setTimeout(() => toast.info('Will not be displayed...'), 0) 
})

But the error should, in fact, be caught in the user component. I don't think you can display a message to the user directly from the server component. But it shouldn't be complicated to throw an error in the server component that could be caught by the user component. I personally use the 'services' or 'repositories' (Do not confuse with Git repositories.). Here is some Documentation on the subject: https://medium.com/backenders-club/consuming-apis-using-the-repository-pattern-in-vue-js-e64671b27b09
Hope this helps!
